# init error: java.net.SocketException: Too many open files

Tags: java, sockets, nullpointerexception

I'm studying java.net and created a simple app which transmits files. I takes files from disk, transform them to the `byte[]` and here is the problem after a few minutes working it drops the folowing:

```
init error: java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

on every attempt to send the file.

**CODE:**

```
    public class Main extends Thread {

        public static final FilesGetter filesGetter = new FilesGetter();
        public static Socket s;
        public static File[] files;

        public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
            s = new Socket("localhost", 3128);

            while (true){
                try{
                    files = filesGetter.getFilesList("/etc/dlp/templates/");
                    Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 3128);
                    args[0] = args[0]+"\n"+s.getInetAddress().getHostAddress()
                            +":"+s.getLocalPort();
                    if (files != null){
                        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
                            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(files[i]);
                            byte[] message = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
                            s.getOutputStream().write(message);

                            byte buf[] = new byte[128*1024];
                            int r = s.getInputStream().read(buf);
                            String data = new String(buf, 0, r);

                            System.out.println(data);
                        }
                    }
                } catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("init error: "+e);
                }
            }       
}
```

how to solve this?

Comment: You cannot continuously open sockets without closing them. You are exhausting the available file handles.

Comment: @JimGarrison oh, I've also found a mistake: I create socet twice: firstly in method and then every time I send messages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a loop in which you open a new socket on each iteration. You never seem to close any of the sockets.  They may get closed when the out-of-scope objects are GC'ed, but you are creating these sockets at a very high rate and exhausting the available file handles.

Close each socket when you are done with it.